# Display UTC based on known timezone

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I know the Time.zone e.g. London, any ideas on how I can display

> (GMT+00:00) London

without assigning

```
Time.zone = "London"
```

and then calling

```
puts Time.zone
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you elaborate more? Do you want to change your timezone system wide, per user, etc.

Comment: I have a timezone set for each user and I want to display this as GMT time instead of the timezone description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call:

```
Time.zone.formatted_offset
```

Which will:

> returns the offset of this time zone as a formatted string, of the format “+HH:MM”.

per: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-formatted_offset

So if you wanted to format the string, you could do:

```
"GMT(#{Time.zone.formatted_offset})"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `to_s` method provides exactly this output.

```
Time.zone.to_s
# => "(GMT+00:00) London"
```